# Magento set product image for multistore view programatically

Tags: image, magento, product

There i am creating a product dynamically from a Helper function. this creates fine. and set image work fine for default store view. but for multistore view, image not selected as 'thumbnail', 'small_image' or 'image'.

```
       $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

        // Build the product
        //$product->setSku('pkg-sku-1');
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4); //default attribute-set
        $product->setTypeId('simple');
        $product->setName($pkg_data['pkg_name']);
        $product->setCategoryIds(array(7)); # some cat id's, my is 7

        $product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); # Website id, my is 1 (default frontend)
        $product->setDescription('EventPackageForOrder');
        $product->setShortDescription($pkg_id);
        $product->setPrice($pkg_data['pkg_price']); # Set some price


        //Default Magento attribute
        $product->setWeight(4.0000);
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
        $product->setStatus(1);
        $product->setTaxClassId(2); # Taxable goods
        $product->setStockData(array(
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 5
        ));

        $im_url_path = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'eventdiscpkgs/event_logo.jpeg'; 
        $im_absolute_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'eventdiscpkgs/event_logo.jpeg';

        $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($im_absolute_path, array ('thumbnail'), false, false);
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($im_absolute_path, array ('small_image'), false, false);
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($im_absolute_path, array ('image'), false, false);



        $product->setHasOptions(true);








        $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
        try {

            $product->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {

            $ex->getMessage();
        }
```

ANY Idea where i can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign image for each store id:

```
foreach($product->getStoreIds() as $storeId) {
    $product->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setImage($im_absolute_path)
        ->setSmallImage($im_absolute_path)
        ->setThumbnail($im_absolute_path);
    $product->save()
}
```

Comment: Here it give me error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1703-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'

Comment: Try before $product->setHasOptions(true); But copy the code one more time. I have changed it a bit.

Comment: i tried with your code, but same error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Comment: Ok. Try to remove my code and before $product->setMediaGallery(); insert the following line: Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

Comment: Hi thanks for your valuable time. it just been fixed with code in your last comment.

Comment: But when i use this code setCurrentStore, i can not add to cart(progeamatically). without this i can do fine. what could be the reason ?

Comment: After saving product -> i switched back to original store. and then send request to cart. and finally this is successful now. Thanks!!!

Comment: How can I set the "default" option for storeview-values? So that it is only necessary to set the value on the "website" layer of magento?